# How can I find missing files in each sub directory?

Tags: batch-file

For a Music collection (D:\Music), I'm looking for specific file names to see if they are there.   They are: artist.jpg, front.jpg, back.jpg, CD.jpg, icon.jpg.  For each Album folder, these files should exist. If they don't, I want to list them, with the desired output to look like this:

```
Artist - Album
artist.jpg
back.jpg
```

In otherwords, in this specific album folder, the files "CD.jpg", "icon.jpg" and "front.jpg" exist, so they should not be listed.

I plan on running this batch file directly from the D:\Music drive itself, but I want to be able to put it on my Desktop, as well (so D:\Music would have to be hardcoded).

I found a batch file to run locally (in an album folder itself) and another to list all directories and even sub directories, too.  The batch file that I've found which lists the subdirectories, too, list first the directories on the first level, then all of the subdirectories.  I'm not sure how my desired output could be created this way, I assume it would have to be a double-loop, so-to-speak.

List all Directories/Subdirectories:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /o:n /a:d') do (
   echo %%a
)
```

List missing files:

```
for %%I in (.) do echo %%~nxI if NOT EXIST front.jpg ECHO front.jpg if NOT EXIST back.jpg ECHO back.jpg if NOT EXIST CD.jpg ECHO CD.jpg if NOT EXIST artists.jpg ECHO artist.jpg if NOT EXIST icon.jpg ECHO icon.jpg
```

How would I put the two code segments together to get what I'm looking for, or is there a different/better approach?

Comment: Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there; you can link back to this one if needed for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just line up many commands in one line. Each `if ... echo ...` has to be on it's own line:

```
for %%I in (.) do (
  echo %%~nxI 
  if NOT EXIST "%%~I\front.jpg" ECHO front.jpg
  if NOT EXIST "%%~I\back.jpg"  ECHO back.jpg
  ... etc.
)
```

But there is a better way anyway:

```
for /r "D:\Music" /d %%I in (*) do (
  echo Folder: %%~nxI
  for %%N in (front back cd artists icon) do (
    if not exist "%%~I\%%~N.jpg" echo   missing: %%N.jpg
  )
)
```

`for /R {startfolder} /D` processes **D**irectories **R**ecursively.
`for %%N in (string1 string2 "string with spaces" string3)` runs the loop for each of the strings.

Comment: Very nice.  I started looking using your "better way".  A couple of things:
I'm noticing that it's checking EVERY folder under music for the missing files, not just the album folders, but also the Artist folders as well.  So in otherwords, I want to make sure it searches only the sub-directories under :D\Music, not the immediate directories, as those are artist names.  Also, I want the results in the format: "Artist - Album".  I do like the other format your script has, with the preceding "Folder" and "Missing".  Can you help me adjust what you have to fit my needs?  Thank you.

Comment: Another problem I'm having is that it is searching multiple levels of directories.  I have one album folder which I have old pictures in, to which I moved them into a folder called OldPics.  The code you have supplied to me will search that directory.  I want to make sure that only the first two directories are being searched, which correspond to Artist and Album.  I have some other sub-sub-directories, but I would hate to have to name all of them in an ignore list.  Is there a better way?

Comment: I figured it out, I'll post the results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code.  I added in some counters but they are not relevant in the end.

```
@echo off
set /A artist = 1
set /A album = 1
set /A missing = 1
set /A AlbumInfo = 0
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd "D:\Music"

for /d %%A in (*) do (
    set /a artist += 1
    for /d %%B in ("%%A\*") do (
        for %%C in (front back cd artist icon) do  (
            if not exist "%%~B\%%~C.jpg" (
                if !AlbumInfo! == 0 (
                    echo %%~nxA - %%~nxB
                    set /A album += 1
                    set "Albuminfo=1"
REM                 echo AlbumInfo: !AlbumInfo!
                )
            echo   Missing: %%C.jpg
            set /A missing += 1
            )
        )
        set "Albuminfo=0"
    )
)

echo Artists: %artist%
echo Albums: %album%
echo Missing: %missing%
REM    echo AlbumInfo: %AlbumInfo%
PAUSE
```